# How LL(1) parser handle Right Associative grammar

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I am trying to find how LL(1) parser handle right associative grammar. For example in case of left associative grammar like this `E->+TE'` first() and follow() works smoothly and parsing table generated easily. But, in case of right-recursive grammar, for example, in case of power like `E->T^E/T` parsing table isn't generating properly. I am searching for resources but found every example avoiding right associativity like powers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LL algorithms handle right-recursion with no problem whatsoever. In fact, the transformation you mention turns a left-associative grammar into a right-associative one, and left-associativity needs to restored by transforming the syntax tree in a semantic rule. So if the production is really right-associative, you can use the same grammar without the need for post- processing the tree.

The problem with  `E -> T ^ E | T` is not that it is right recursive. The problem is that the two right-hand sides start with the same non-terminal, making prediction impossible. The solution is left-factoring, which will produce `E -> T E'` / `E' -> ε | ^ T E'`.